# DCGAN for RGB dataset strange results

Tags: c++, pytorch, conv-neural-network, libtorch

I am implementing a DCGAN network in LibTorch/Pytorch. I am following the official example in https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/cpp/dcgan/dcgan.cpp .
The only differences between my problem and the example are:

- My dataset is composed by RGB pictures (CelebA dataset) while the one from the example is black and white (MNIST)
- The dimensions of my pictures are 64x64 while MNIST pictures are 28x28

That said here is my code:

```
#include <torch/torch.h>

#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include "CustomDataset.h"
#include "parameters.h"

// The size of the noise vector fed to the generator.
const int64_t kNoiseSize = 100;

// The batch size for training.
const int64_t kBatchSize = 64;

// The number of epochs to train.
const int64_t kNumberOfEpochs = 30;

// Where to find the MNIST dataset.
const char* kDataFolder = "./data";

// After how many batches to create a new checkpoint periodically.
const int64_t kCheckpointEvery = 20;

// How many images to sample at every checkpoint.
const int64_t kNumberOfSamplesPerCheckpoint = 10;


// After how many batches to log a new update with the loss value.
const int64_t kLogInterval = 10;

using namespace torch;

struct DCGANGeneratorImpl : nn::Module {
    DCGANGeneratorImpl(int kNoiseSize)
            : conv1(nn::ConvTranspose2dOptions(kNoiseSize, 256, 4)
                            .bias(false)),
              batch_norm1(256),
              conv2(nn::ConvTranspose2dOptions(256, 128, 4)
                            .stride(2)
                            .padding(1)
                            .bias(false)),
              batch_norm2(128),
              conv3(nn::ConvTranspose2dOptions(128, 64, 4)
                            .stride(2)
                            .padding(1)
                            .bias(false)),
              batch_norm3(64),
              conv4(nn::ConvTranspose2dOptions(64, 32, 4)
                            .stride(2)
                            .padding(1)
                            .bias(false)),
              batch_norm4(32),
              conv5(nn::ConvTranspose2dOptions(32, 3, 4)
                            .stride(2)
                            .padding(1)
                            .bias(false))

    {
        register_module("conv1", conv1);
        register_module("conv2", conv2);
        register_module("conv3", conv3);
        register_module("conv4", conv4);
        register_module("conv5", conv5);
        register_module("batch_norm1", batch_norm1);
        register_module("batch_norm2", batch_norm2);
        register_module("batch_norm3", batch_norm3);
        register_module("batch_norm4", batch_norm4);

    }

    torch::Tensor forward(torch::Tensor x)
    {
        x = torch::relu(batch_norm1(conv1(x)));
        x = torch::relu(batch_norm2(conv2(x)));
        x = torch::relu(batch_norm3(conv3(x)));
        x = torch::relu(batch_norm4(conv4(x)));
        x = torch::tanh(conv5(x));
        return x;
    }


    nn::ConvTranspose2d conv1, conv2, conv3, conv4, conv5;
    nn::BatchNorm2d batch_norm1, batch_norm2, batch_norm3, batch_norm4;
};

TORCH_MODULE(DCGANGenerator);

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    torch::manual_seed(1);

    // Create the device we pass around based on whether CUDA is available.
    torch::Device device(torch::kCPU);
    if (torch::cuda::is_available()) {
        std::cout << "CUDA is available! Training on GPU." << std::endl;
        device = torch::Device(torch::kCUDA);
    }

    DCGANGenerator generator(kNoiseSize);
    generator->to(device);

    nn::Sequential discriminator(
            // Layer 1
            nn::Conv2d(
                    nn::Conv2dOptions(3, 64, 4).stride(2).padding(1).bias(false)),
            nn::LeakyReLU(nn::LeakyReLUOptions().negative_slope(0.2)),
            //output is 32x32
            // Layer 2
            nn::Conv2d(
                    nn::Conv2dOptions(64, 128, 4).stride(2).padding(1).bias(false)),
            nn::BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn::LeakyReLU(nn::LeakyReLUOptions().negative_slope(0.2)),
            //output is 16x16
            // Layer 3
            nn::Conv2d(
                    nn::Conv2dOptions(128, 64, 4).stride(2).padding(1).bias(false)),
            nn::BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn::LeakyReLU(nn::LeakyReLUOptions().negative_slope(0.2)),
            //output is 8x8
            // Layer 4
            nn::Conv2d(
                    nn::Conv2dOptions(64, 32, 5).stride(1).padding(0).bias(false)),
            nn::LeakyReLU(nn::LeakyReLUOptions().negative_slope(0.2)),
            // output is 4x4
            // Layer 5
            nn::Conv2d(
                    nn::Conv2dOptions(32, 1, 4).stride(1).padding(0).bias(false)),
            nn::Sigmoid());
    discriminator->to(device);

    // Where all my pictures are;
    std::string file_location{"dataset/img_align_celeba/*.jpg"};
    auto dataset = CustomDataset(file_location).map(data::transforms::Stack<>());

    const int64_t batches_per_epoch =
            std::ceil(dataset.size().value() / static_cast<double>(kBatchSize));

    auto data_loader = torch::data::make_data_loader(
            std::move(dataset),
            torch::data::DataLoaderOptions().batch_size(kBatchSize).workers(2));


    torch::optim::Adam generator_optimizer(
            generator->parameters(), torch::optim::AdamOptions(2e-4).beta1(0.5));
    torch::optim::Adam discriminator_optimizer(
            discriminator->parameters(), torch::optim::AdamOptions(2e-4).beta1(0.5));


    int64_t checkpoint_counter = 1;
    for (int64_t epoch = 1; epoch <= kNumberOfEpochs; ++epoch) {
        int64_t batch_index = 0;
        for (torch::data::Example<>& batch : *data_loader) {
            // Train discriminator with real images.
            discriminator->zero_grad();
            torch::Tensor real_images = batch.data.to(device);
            torch::Tensor real_labels =
                    torch::empty(batch.data.size(0), device).uniform_(0.8, 1.0);
            torch::Tensor real_output = discriminator->forward(real_images);
            torch::Tensor d_loss_real =
                    torch::binary_cross_entropy(real_output, real_labels);
            d_loss_real.backward();

            // Train discriminator with fake images.
            torch::Tensor noise =
                    torch::randn({batch.data.size(0), kNoiseSize, 1, 1}, device);
            torch::Tensor fake_images = generator->forward(noise);
            torch::Tensor fake_labels = torch::zeros(batch.data.size(0), device);
            torch::Tensor fake_output = discriminator->forward(fake_images.detach());
            torch::Tensor d_loss_fake =
                    torch::binary_cross_entropy(fake_output, fake_labels);
            d_loss_fake.backward();

            torch::Tensor d_loss = d_loss_real + d_loss_fake;
            discriminator_optimizer.step();

            // Train generator.
            generator->zero_grad();
            fake_labels.fill_(1);
            fake_output = discriminator->forward(fake_images);
            torch::Tensor g_loss =
                    torch::binary_cross_entropy(fake_output, fake_labels);
            g_loss.backward();
            generator_optimizer.step();
            batch_index++;      

            if (batch_index % kCheckpointEvery == 0) {
                // Checkpoint the model and optimizer state.
                torch::save(generator, "generator-checkpoint.pt");
                torch::save(generator_optimizer, "generator-optimizer-checkpoint.pt");
                torch::save(discriminator, "discriminator-checkpoint.pt");
                torch::save(
                        discriminator_optimizer, "discriminator-optimizer-checkpoint.pt");
                // Sample the generator and save the images.
                torch::Tensor samples = generator->forward(torch::randn(
                        {kNumberOfSamplesPerCheckpoint, kNoiseSize, 1, 1}, device));
                torch::save(
                        samples,
                        torch::str("dcgan-sample-", checkpoint_counter, ".pt"));
                std::cout << "\n-> checkpoint " << ++checkpoint_counter << '\n';
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Training complete!" << std::endl;
}
```

I save the minibatches from time to time and plot the result of inputing noise over the Generator. The problem is that in the MNIST example results are correct but in my case for each output picture I see like 9 smaller pictures with faces instead of one (see the picture attached).

[image]

How is it possible that the generator is outputting a correct shape but with 9 almost identical faces instead of one?